# Django Multiple Form Submission: One form overwriting all form objects

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to write a view that displays a number of forms, one for each model instance that is returned by an object query.  That way the user can fill out multiple forms at once and then data for all objects gets saved on `POST`.  Here's what I have:

View:

```
def formView(request, attr):
     object_list = MyModel.objects.filter(attribute1=attr)
     if request.method == 'POST':
          form_list = [MyModelForm(request.POST, instance=x) for x in object_list]
          if all(form.is_valid for form in form_list):
              for form in form_list:
                  form.save()
              return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
     else:
          form_list = [MyModelForm(instance=x) for x in object_list]
     return render(request, 'formView.html', {'form_list':form_list})
```

HTML:

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Field1</th>
                <th>Field2</th>
                <th>Field3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for form in form_list %}
            <tr>
                <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                <td>{{ field }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                </form>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but here's what I think my code is currently doing: when a user fills out the forms on the page and then clicks one of the `Submit` buttons, the form corresponding to that `Submit` button sends only its data to my view, which then proceeds to save that data into all of the forms in `form_list`, thereby writing that same data to all of the corresponding objects in my database (which is obviously not what I want).

What I would like is something like a single `Submit` button for the whole page, so that the data for each form in the page is sent back with its associated form and saved to the appropriate corresponding object in the database.  Is this possible?

Comment: A browser will send only the form your submit button is related with and it won't submit the others. This is just W3C browser behaviour. Hence that every `<form>` has its own method (GET/POST) and action URI. What you want is to use the FormSets as now answered already; note that it uses a single form element to render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try a FormSet associated to a Model? You can define the query to select the objects you want to edit and Django takes care of (almost) everything.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset

If you want to pursue your approach (more than one Form per page, or more than one FormSet per page) use the `prefix` attribute:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#subclassing-forms
and use only one `<form>` tag with a single `Submit` button.

The example:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view

Comment: I tried the FormSet method as I like using all of the "batteries included" parts of Django, but then realized it wouldn't work because I need to exclude one of the form fields and but still display its value, and I can't do that within the `{% for form in formset %}` loop.  However, the `prefix` way works quite well, and +1 for mentioning that I then need only one `<form>` tag and one `Submit` button.

Comment: I started to work with forms only recently, so I'm not sure I understood what you mean when you say you can't exclude one of the form fields. Did you try to use the third method explained here?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template
What is the problem?

Comment: Excluding the form field is not the problem, the problem comes in my template when I loop through the forms using `{% for form in formset %}`.  If I exclude a field when defining my formset, it won't appear in any of the forms inside of that loop in my template.  But I still want to display the data for the excluded field, and I have no access to that data in my formset. So using the `prefix` method, instead of sending just the simple `form_list` from my code example to my template, I create a list of `value,form` tuples, and then I can loop over both simultaneously in the template.

Comment: Yes, you can not exclude the field, otherwise you don't have it anymore. But I don't see why you can't do the third method:
`{{ formset.management_form }}{% for form in formset %}{% for field in form %}{% endfor %}{% endfor %}`

Comment: This is probably my fault for posting code that is a bit simpler than what I want to do.  I want to loop over forms that exclude a particular field, because I don't want the values in that field edited for existing objects.  However, I do still want to display those values next to each form to help users identify the object instance.  As far as I can tell, there's no way to loop over the values of excluded fields inside a `{% for form in formset %}` loop.  So I created a data structure that includes both the forms I want to loop over AND the data I want to display (but keep from being edited).

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`prefix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) in the form, so that each form is identified separately. `x.id` would be better for prefix.

Something like:

```
def formView(request, attr):
     object_list = MyModel.objects.filter(attribute1=attr)
     if request.method == 'POST':
          form_list = [MyModelForm(request.POST, instance=x, prefix=str(x.id)) for x in object_list]
          if all(form.is_valid for form in form_list):
              for form in form_list:
                  form.save()
              return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
     else:
          form_list = [MyModelForm(instance=x, prefix=str(x.id)) for x in object_list]
     return render(request, 'formView.html', {'form_list':form_list})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  This seems like the quickest way to achieve what I'm looking for, as it requires only minimal change to my code.  However, now when the user clicks `Submit` on one of the forms, the rest of the forms go blank and that triggers all of the `field.errors` for those forms.  Why is that happening?

Comment: @GChorn, check you get data of all forms in `request.POST`.

Comment: I realized the problem from reading the other answer--with this method I need to use a single `<form>` tag with only one `Submit` button, and then just iterate over my `form_list` within that `<form>` element.

Comment: @GChorn, yes, all forms should be in one `<form>` tag with one `submit` button.